# Python/Pandas: Counting the number of times a value less than x appears in a column

Tags: python, count, pandas

Hi I have a file of variables that I have read in as sim.

```
>>sim.head()
        SIM0    212321
        SIM1    9897362
        SIM2    345
        SIM3    2345
        SIM4    79727367
```

I have assigned the first value of the column to original:

```
original=sim[0]
212321
```

I would like to use pandas to count the number of times a number less than 212321 appears in sim.
Is there a way to do this without a loop?

Answer (score 3):

If `sim` is a Series, you could do this:

```
import pandas as pd

sim = pd.Series([212321, 9897362, 345, 2345, 79727367],
                index=map('SIM{}'.format, range(5)))

orig = sim[0]
num_smaller_items = (sim < orig).sum()
print(num_smaller_items)
# 2
```